# MongoDB: How to make two unions to the same collection with matrices

Tags: mongodb

I have user records with posts and posts shared with them, that is, users can share the posts with other users. I need to be able to bring or get only the posts shared with him, using as a reference the id of the user who shared the post and the id of the post.

when I use the user id as a reference, it works, but when I try to combine it with the id of the post it does not get anything, this happens when I try to use only the id of the post to get the shared posts.

This would be the structure of the records

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cd573b2bb9ad84f9bba2f74"),
    "name" : "name 4",
    "posts" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5cd573b2bb9ad84f9bba2f72"),
            "name" : "post 1"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5cd573b2bb9ad84f9bba2f73"),
            "name" : "post 2"
        }
    ],
    "postSharedWithMe" : [ 
        {
            "user_id" : "5cd4aaedfcf8d8583cf97494",
            "post_id" : "5cd4aaedfcf8d8583cf97492"
        }, 
        {
            "user_id" : "5cd4aaedfcf8d8583cf97494",
            "post_id" : "5cd4aaedfcf8d8583cf97493"
        }
    ]
}
```

and in this way he tried to consult them

```
db.users.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "_id": ObjectId("5cd573b2bb9ad84f9bba2f74") }},
    { $unwind:"$postSharedWithMe" },
    { $unwind:"$posts" },
    {
      $lookup:
         {
           from: "users",
           let: { 
              user_id: { "$toObjectId": "$postSharedWithMe.user_id"},
              post_id : { "$toObjectId": "$postSharedWithMe.post_id"}
           },

           pipeline: [
              { $match:
                 { $expr:
                    { $and:
                       [
                         { $eq: [ "$_id", "$$user_id" ] },
                         { $eq: [ "$posts._id", "$$post_id" ] }
                       ]
                    }
                 }
              },            
           ],
           as: "sharedPosts"
         }
    },
    { $unwind:"$sharedPosts" },
    { "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "sharedPosts": { "$push": "$sharedPosts" }
        }
    }
])
```

and this is the result:
Fetched 0 record(s) in 0ms

and this is what I expected

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cd573b2bb9ad84f9bba2f74"),
    "name" : "username",
    "posts" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5cd573b2bb9ad84f9bba2f72"),
            "name" : "post 1"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5cd573b2bb9ad84f9bba2f73"),
            "name" : "post 2"
        }
    ],
    "sharedPosts" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("id"),
            "name" : "shared post"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("id"),
            "name" : "shared post"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

apparently I needed to go through all the posts first while referring to the shared posts, the result of this was an array, now I just needed to make the $ unwind and compare with $ eq and it worked!

```
db.users.aggregate([
    { $match: { "_id": ObjectId("5cd573b2bb9ad84f9bba2f74") }},
    { $unwind: "$postSharedWithMe" },    
    {
      $lookup:
         {
           from: "users",
           let: { 
              user_id: { $toObjectId: "$postSharedWithMe.user_id"},
              post_id : { $toObjectId: "$postSharedWithMe.post_id"}
           },

           pipeline: [
              { $match:
                 { $expr:
                    { $and:
                       [
                         { $eq: [ "$$user_id", "$_id" ] },
                         { $in: ["$$post_id", "$posts._id" ] },                    
                       ]
                    }
                 }
              }, 
              { $unwind: "$posts" },
              { $match: { $expr: { $eq: [ "$posts._id", "$$post_id" ] } } },       
           ],
           as: "sharedPosts"
         }
    },
    { $unwind: "$sharedPosts" },
    { $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            name: { "$first": "$name" },
            posts: { "$first": "$posts" },
            sharedPosts: { $push: 
                "$sharedPosts.posts" 
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Please provide Context with your answer its very hard to assume what you changed and why did u do it?